# Open of new powerpoint presentation using Excel fails

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a powerpoint deck from excel where the I use the row in excel to create a slide, I am stuck on opening the presentation.  I am getting an error "Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed. Read a lot of other posts on this but missing something that is likely stupid and obvious.

Here is the code

```
Sub LoadPPTDescriptions()

'   Purpose: Rowlevel copy between worksheets
'   Support: 
'   

'   Define global variables
Dim CurrWorkbook As Workbook
Dim RowValueStream As String
Dim RowInitiative As String
Dim RowPriority As Integer
Dim CurrWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim CurrWorksheetName As String
Dim CurrRange As Range
Dim RangeStr As String
Dim RowStr As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim PPTSlideNum As Integer
Dim PPTObect As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTFile As String
Dim PPTTableRow As Integer





'   Set Current Workbook and set target worksheet
Set CurrWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

'   Initialize counter to point to first row in target worksheet
TargetRow = 5

'   Initialize Powerpoint Object
Set PPTObject = New PowerPoint.Application
PPTObject.Visible = True


'   Create Powerpoint Deck
PPTFile = "C:\TEST99.ppt"
Debug.Print "FILENAME>" + PPTFile + "<FILENAME"
Set PPTPres = PPTObject.Presentations.Open(PPTFile) 'GET ERROR HERE - Method open of object presentations failed 

End Sub
```

Comment: That means something is wrong with the filepath.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the path.  Tried with exactly what you see, also tried c:\Users\Name\Documents\TEST99.pptx.   Copied the file path from the variable went to a command window, an pasted the path in after a CD command in the command window and it worked, very baffled on this.

Comment: there have been times that ```Set PPTObject = New PowerPoint.Application``` wouldn't work for me where ```Set PPTObject = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")``` would work. IDK why.

Comment: Changed "Set PPTObject = New PowerPoint.Application" to "Set PPTObject = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")" No joy.

Comment: Fixed the missing J in Object in the Dim statements but that did not help either.  Still stopping on "Set PPTPres = PPTObject.Presentations.Open(PPTFile)"

Comment: @braX Did you see anything wrong with the open statement, I just published the fragment up to where it blew up. .

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with it. I would try putting it in a different folder instead of the root folder, and also make sure that file is not open in some other instance. (reboot to make sure, as it may be open in an invisible unclosed instance)

Comment: You can also try using `.Add` instead of `.Open` to see if you get the same error.